# My python program for finding the slope of a line is returning errors for certain coordinates while working fine for others

Tags: python, math

This is my code:

```
import os

def main():
    x1 = int(input('Enter x1: '))
    y1 = int(input('Enter y1: '))
    
    print('\n')
    
    x2 = int(input('Enter x2: '))
    y2 = int(input('Enter y2: '))
        
    print('\n')
    
    slopeDec = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

    def hcf(x, y):  
        if x > y:  
            smaller = y  
        else:  
            smaller = x  
        for i in range(1,smaller + 1):  
            if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):  
                hcf = i  
        return hcf  
    
    x = (x2-x1)
    y = (y2-y1)

    highestCommonFactor = hcf(x, y)
    newX = x/highestCommonFactor
    newY = y/highestCommonFactor
     
     
    print('\n')
    
    print("Decimal Value: "+str(int(slopeDec)))
         
    print('\n')
    
    print("Fraction Value: "+str(int(newY))+"/"+str(int(newX)))
         
    print('\n')
    
    
    chc = input('Press anything except n to restart the calculator: ')
    while chc != 'n':
        os.system('cls')
        main()
    else: 
        exit()
    
main()
```

When I input the coordinates (2, 4) and (5, 6), it returns the slope fine. However, when I input the coordinates (2, -3) and (1, -3), it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\murkut23\Desktop\python files\slope.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\murkut23\Desktop\python files\slope.py", line 30, in main
    highestCommonFactor = hcf(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\murkut23\Desktop\python files\slope.py", line 25, in hcf
    return hcf
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hcf' referenced before assignment
```

I cannot understand where I'm going wrong and any help will be appreciated a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the values (2, -3) and (1, -3), `smaller` will be 0, which creates the range `range(1,1)`. However, since the end point of the range is not included, the code in the for loop will never be executed, and thus, `hcf` won't be initialized.

I would suggest to initialize `hcf` to a reasonable value, e.g., 1, before the loop.